# Multiple HTTP request to the same page without consuming much CPU

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, httprequest, cpu-usage

Currently, I'm trying to improve a code that sends multiple HTTP requests to a webpage until it can capture some text (which the code localizes through a known pattern) or until 180 seconds runs out (the time we wait for the page to give us an answer).
This is the part of the code (a little edited for privacy purposes):

```
       if matches == None:
            txt = "No answer til now"
            print(txt)
            Solution = False
            start = time.time()
            interval = 0
            while interval < 180:
                response   = requests.get("page address")
                subject  = response.text
                matches = re.search(pattern, subject, re.IGNORECASE)
                if matches != None:
                    Solution =matches.group(1)
                    time = "{:.2f}".format(time.time()-start) 
                    txt = "Found an anwswer "+ Solution + "time needed : "+ time
                    print(txt)
                    break
                interval = time.time()-start
        else:
            Solution = matches.group(1)
```

It runs OK, but I was told that doing "infinite requests in a loop" could cause an hight CPU usage of the server. Do you guys know of something I can use in order to avoid that?

Ps: I heard that in PHP people use curl_multi_select() for things like these. Don't know if I'm correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Usually an HTTP REST API will specify in the documentation how many requests you can make in a given time period against which endpoint resources.

For a website, if you are not hitting a request limit and getting flagged/banned for too many requests, then you should be okay to continuously loop like this, but you may want to introduce a `time.sleep` call into your `while` loop.

An alternative to the 180 second timeout:

Since HTTP requests are I/O operations and can take a variable amount of time, you may want to change your exit case for the loop to a certain amount of requests (like 25 or something) and then incorporate the aforementioned `sleep` call.

That could look like:

```py
# ...
if matches is None:
    solution = None
    num_requests = 25
    start = time.time()

    while num_requests:
        response = requests.get("page address")

        if response.ok:  # It's good to attempt to handle potential HTTP/Connectivity errors
            subject = response.text
            matches = re.search(pattern, subject, re.IGNORECASE)
            if matches:
                solution = matches.group(1)
                elapsed = "{:.2f}".format(time.time()-start) 
                txt = "Found an anwswer " + solution + "time needed : " + elapsed
            print(txt)
            break
        else:
            # Maybe raise an error here?
            pass

        time.sleep(2)
        num_requests -= 1

else:
    solution = matches.group(1)
```

**Notes**:

- Regarding PHP's [`curl_multi_select`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) - (NOT a PHP expert here...) it seems that this function is designed to allow you to watch multiple connections to different URLs in an asynchronous manner. Async doesn't really apply to your use case here because you are only scraping one webpage (URL), and are just waiting for some data to appear there.
- If the `response.text` you are searching through is HTML and you aren't already using it somewhere else in your code, I would recommend [Beautiful Soup](https://scrapy.org/) or [scrapy](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to (before regex) for searching for string patterns in webpage markup.